# Plant growing very rapidly near my house

Tags: species-identification

please see attached photos of a plant, that is growing rapidly near my house. All my friends failed to classify this plant. Can any botanist/biologist help to discover the species of this plant?
Thank you in advance! [image: Mysterious plant - photo 1]

[image: Mysterious plant - photo 2]

Comment: Help us. Where do you live?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a young Empress Tree [(*Paulownia tomentosa*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paulownia_tomentosa)

Native to China, it is an invasive species in the USA. [looks beautiful when full grown however](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/90/50/7d/90507d48dd87e39ef5151f006f44042a.jpg)